# Is there any way that I could get the table from one running SP and give it to another SP in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm new to the SQL DBA role. I have a Stored Procedure (SP1) that might run multiple times per day. It runs an expensive `SELECT` on table1 that may take 15 minutes to be done. I have another Stored Procedure (SP2) that runs a `SELECT` on table1 that may take 1 second to be done.

After SP1 runs, SP2 has to wait until SP1 done! Is there any way that I could get the required resource (like select from table1) to run SP2 and after the SP2 is done, give it back to SP1?

I don't want to use `SELECT WITH (NOLOCK)` because other queries may try to edit table1.

Comment: Hmmm.  You know the answer, but you don't want to use it.

Comment: Well, I want to know if there is a cleaner way or not.

Comment: So to clarify, SP1 takes exclusive table locks such that SP2 can't read from the table until SP1 is done? And what do you mean by "give it back to SP1"? Give what back?

Comment: Yes exactly. Give the table back to SP1 to continue its SELECT.

Comment: Are both tables performing a `SELECT` rather than `INSERT`/`UPDATE`? If so what is stopping SP2 from running as they should both only be taking shared locks on the table?

Comment: You mean "both SP"? No. Sometimes they could perform `INSERT/UPDATE` too.

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: We had a similar problem with an old legacy database. Everybody was trying to fuddle around with indexes, `RECOMPILE`, even `NOLOCK`, but finally the SP was rewritten and ran about 8 times faster... If you don't give away to much, you might post the code of SP1 plus structural information (esp. indexes). Maybe there are better screws to tune...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question would be "no". It seems you have a very long-running query in SP1 that takes shared locks across Table1 such that any `UPDATE` or `INSERT` in SP2 has to wait until SP1 is completed so that the requisite exclusive locks can be taken (you haven't mentioned transactions/isolation levels so I'm going to assume that it's the `SELECT` itself that takes time not any subsequent processing - although you have said that SP1 may then perform some `UPDATE`s or `INSERT`s of its own). From what I can gather, you want SP1 to release its locks in the midst of its `SELECT` such that SP2 can perform its `UPDATE`s and then, once SP2 releases its locks then allow SP1 to continue its `SELECT`. I'm afraid this goes against SQL's locking logic and indeed against ACID principles. Were it to work as you want it to then in order to ensure consistent results SP1 would have to restart its `SELECT` every time SP2 (or another process) performed an `UPDATE`, with catastrophic consequences for database performance.

It sounds like you need to look at restructuring your stored procedures/ application. To have an SP running regularly that takes 15 minutes and potentially locks up a table sounds like a major bottleneck. Can it not be broken down - perhaps incorporating some of SP2's logic into one of the segments? Also, why does it take so long? Is there not indexing that can be applied to reduce the time the `SELECT` takes and also avoid the kind of table/range locks that you seem to be suffering from?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)?

You would definitely need to test it out on a non-Production environment first but it should hopefully be an alternative to `NOLOCK`

However, Books Online says that:

> The net effect of snapshot isolation is that the transaction sees all of the data as it existed at the start of the transaction, without honoring or placing any locks on the underlying tables. This can result in performance improvements in situations where there is contention.

There is a caveat here that it could be **detrimental to your TempDB** but if you have the space for it, it may be of some help to you.

I would definitely read up about it first and maybe check out some other [answers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5015/46185).